# Changing the way that a SiriKit payment can be phrased

Tags: ios, sirikit

I'm trying to make a bill payment app using SiriKit's `INPayBillIntent`. I've set a custom bill organization type as below:

```
   INVocabulary.shared().setVocabularyStrings(["Devon"], of: .paymentsOrganizationName)
```

The problem is with custom vocabulary -- I want to pay the bill in Siri by saying "Pay Devon" but Siri only recognizes the intent if I say "Pay Devon Bill"  like saying "Pay Water Bill".

Can I change this?

Comment: What is Devon in this case

Comment: It's an example name for a payment organization.

Comment: i am not sure but i might not be possible

Comment: Can you have the code check for the words “pay” and “bill” if pay is there but bill isn’t append bill?

Comment: I think it's not possible, the intent only gives me the organization name.